# Is it possible to have an iMac maintain target display mode even through sleep/screensaver

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, display, sleep-wake, target-display

I want to be able to make it so that my iMac doesn't exit target display mode until the thunderbolt cable is pulled from my Macbook. I love target display mode in theory, but every time I lock my Macbook, the iMac exits target display mode. I then have to use the iMac keyboard to set the computer back to target display mode, which isn't a big deal when doing it just a couple times, but is incredibly obnoxious in aggregate.

Is it possible to make it so target display mode stays even after locking the connected laptop/computer?

Comment: Will this be as simple as preventing sleep on the MacBook but having the screen locked? Have you tried that avenue?

Comment: This might be useful - haven't tried it out yet though https://github.com/duanefields/VirtualKVM - via http://stackoverflow.com/a/24408759/1469259